# IsoDateTimeConverter and JsonSerializerSettings: differentiate DateTime with DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset, jsonserializer

In my C# models I use both `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`, eg:

```
   class Foo 
   {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }
   }
```

When I serialize to JSON, I do it like this:

```
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
  foo.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

  var isoDateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
  isoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd";

  var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
  serializerSettings.Converters.Add(isoDateTimeConverter);

  JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
  serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
```

This will produce this JSON:

```
 {
     Date = "2019-02-26",
     CreationDate = "2019-02-26"
 }
```

Both `Date` and `CreationDate` are serialized the same way due to `IsoDateTimeConverter`

**What I'd like to do is to differentiate the serialization of `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset`**

My goal is to get this JSON:

```
 {
     Date = "2019-02-26",
     CreationDate = "2019-02-26T12:03:00-03:00"
 }
```

How can I achieve this?

Additional info:

- When my C# model uses `DateTime`, I save it as `Date` in SQL Server
- When my C# model uses `DateTimeOffset`, I save it as `DateTimeOffset` in SQL Server
- I'm using EF Code First

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class DateFormatConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public DateFormatConverter(string format)
    {
        DateTimeFormat = format;
    }
}
```

Specify the format for each `Date` properties

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-dd")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Without additional settings, you can `Serialize`

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
foo.CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

OUTPUT

```
{"Date":"2020-02-26","CreationDate":"2020-02-26T15:30:19-03:00"}
```

Comment: It is throwing: `JsonconverterAttribute does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments`

Comment: Solved above error by updating Newtonsoft.Json from 5.0.8 to 12.0.3

Comment: Perfect @sports